# How to get url path to file from absolute file path - Convert absolute path to url path - PHP

Tags: php, url, path

I have stored images path as absolute file path on server disk:

```
/var/www/u1234567/data/www/somesampledomain.xyz/mediaimages/48fa6c736b75e1da485656e97b7d76f9.png
```

I want to convert this absolute path -> to url path like:

```
https://somesampledomain.xyz/mediaimages/48fa6c736b75e1da485656e97b7d76f9.png
```

I can just trim this unnessesary part with `/var/www...`. But is there some more univirsal way, without the hardcode part with `/var/www/u1234567/data/www/`?

Comment: Did you try Regex?

Answer (score 1):

I find it useful to have something like the below in the global config file:

```php
define('BASE_DIR', '/var/www/u1234567/data/www/somesampledomain.xyz/');
define('BASE_URL', 'https://somesampledomain.xyz/');
```

Which is useful for translating urls and paths, in various places. Though for simplicity it's usually more like:

```php
define('BASE_DIR', realpath('../htdocs/'));
```

Then you can:

```php
$path = '/var/www/u1234567/data/www/somesampledomain.xyz/mediaimages/48fa6c736b75e1da485656e97b7d76f9.png';
$url  = 'https://somesampledomain.xyz/mediaimages/48fa6c736b75e1da485656e97b7d76f9.png';

function path_to_url($path) {
    return preg_replace('/^'.preg_quote(BASE_DIR, '/').'/', BASE_URL, $path, 1);
}

function url_to_path($url) {
    return preg_replace('/^'.preg_quote(BASE_URL, '/').'/', BASE_DIR, $url, 1);
}

var_dump(
    $url,
    path_to_url($path),
    $path,
    url_to_path($url)
);
```

Output:

```
string(77) "https://somesampledomain.xyz/mediaimages/48fa6c736b75e1da485656e97b7d76f9.png"
string(77) "https://somesampledomain.xyz/mediaimages/48fa6c736b75e1da485656e97b7d76f9.png"
string(96) "/var/www/u1234567/data/www/somesampledomain.xyz/mediaimages/48fa6c736b75e1da485656e97b7d76f9.png"
string(96) "/var/www/u1234567/data/www/somesampledomain.xyz/mediaimages/48fa6c736b75e1da485656e97b7d76f9.png"
```

Ref:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote

Comment: Why preg replace? isn't it simpler to just substr()?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this simple php script**

```
<?php
$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo("$link");
?>
```

*It will show your full website url with current file like: `http://site .com/file.php`*